# Diagnose routing issues on aws between vpc's

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, vpc

I am having a routing issue between vpc's and subnets. I am wondering is there a simple way, or steps, to work out what is blocking access i.e nacl's, sg's, route tables...

I come across this quite often and the only way I know to test is to telnet with port, but this is not super helpful, when it could be any of the above.

In this case specifically, I am trying to route from one(shared services) peered vpc through to another, and then to an instance in a subnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some quick pointers :

Identify the source of the issue, check the route tables of the subnets with the resources that are impacted:

**Public subnets**

- Confirm that the route table destination has a default route (0.0.0.0/0 for IPv4 and ::/0 for IPv6) that points to an internet gateway.

**Subnets using NAT instances or NAT gateways**

- Under **Subnets**, choose your private subnet.
- Choose the **Route Table** view, and confirm that the route table has a default route that points to a NAT instance or gateway.
- Confirm that the NAT device is launched in a public subnet and perform the checks required for public subnets listed in the previous section.

  **Note**: If you're using a NAT instance, be sure you've disabled the [source destination check.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#EIP_Disable_SrcDestCheck)

**Subnets using VPC peering connections**

- Choose **Peering Connections**, and choose your peering connection
- Confirm its status is **Active**.
- From the navigation pane, choose **Subnets**, and choose the subnets of the Amazon VPC that you want to connect using a peering connection.
- Choose the **Route Tables** view, and confirm that they have routes to CIDR with specific subnets or to the entire CIDR of the peered Amazon VPC, including the peering connection noted in step 2
- Confirm that the route tables include all the subnets for the peered Amazon VPC.

  **Note**: Confirm there are no [invalid VPC peering connection configurations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/invalid-peering-configurations.html)

You can read more about it [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-vpc-route-table/)

Hope this helps!